# Clarification on correct usage of TFS to publish Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to setup CI via TFS 2015, I've got a solution that has got 2 main Web application that currently we deploy manually editing the config files and so on (which sometimes leads to errors)

I've read about build/release process and in the past I've used Jenkins as build server. But till today I've got a question and that's related to when apply the transformation of XML config files.

In my current VTFS2015 setup I've created a build process and I build the project with the following line

`msbuild /p:Configuration=Test /p:PublishProfile=Test /p:DeployOnBuild=true xxx\xxx.csproj`

This creates me in the folder `obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp` the package

Is this ok? or should this be done in the release management tab? Consider in my farm I've

- Test (from DEV trunk)
- Staging (from Dev trunk as well)
- Production (from production trunk on 3 machines)

My goal is to have them automatically delivered on the machines, but I don't know the right moment to apply the transformation (during the build I can use the publish feature, during the RM I can use a ps1 script)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think this thread will helps: [What TFS 2017 build task applies web.config transforms during TFS builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296796/what-tfs-2017-build-task-applies-web-config-transforms-during-tfs-builds)

To apply the transformations you can use the extension: [Apply transformations](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jungeriusit.jungit-apply-transformations) in vNext build process.

> Usually it should be a package and be used in a deploy task such as
>   [Deploy: WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploy/README_IISAppDeploy.md) or [Azure App Service
>   Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps) to achieved the deployment.
>
> 1) Can transforms be engaged in both Builds and Releases?
>
> *Yes, you could also do this in a build pipeline with the useage of build deploy task. You need to add the task after the publish build
>   artifacts task.*
>
> 2) Does TFS 2017 require a lot of special handling to engage a
>   transform file?
>
> > **update**
> >
> > The BuildConfiguration variable is different in TFS 2017, it's inside
> >     the **MSBuild task**! Transforms are now applied according
> >     to the MSBuild task Configuration setting.
>
> *Edit the  `.proj` file is a method to do the transform. If you don't need to change the transform, it will auto do it during the build.You
>   could also use some 3-rd party task/extension for extra transform such
>   as: [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform)*
>
> Usually we separate the build and release for the deployment, cause
>   it's easy to configure multiple  environments and easy to debug issue.
>   You definitely could do this only in build but with a bloated process.
>   You could refer this tutorial: [Build and Deploy Azure Web Apps using
>   Team Foundation Server/Services vNext Builds.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/04/01/build-and-deploy-azure-web-apps-using-team-foundation-serverservices-vnext-builds/)
>
> For a separate build and release solution, you could take a look at
>   this blog: [Using web.config transforms and Release Manager – TFS
>   2017/Team Services edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alming/2017/02/09/using-web-config-transforms-and-release-manager-tfs-2017team-services-edition/)